# ASP.NET MVC - наполнение динамической таблицы, проблема с передачей в контроллер

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Добрый день. подскажите как реализовать. Имеется представление, которое было создано VS автоматически + EF, представление реализует шаблон Create. Суть представления: добавление в БД данных  приказа, + нужно добавить функционал с помощью которого можно было набрасывать ответственных лиц в таблицу, т.е. нужен динимаческий набор данных. Динамический набор делаю таким образом: выбираю с помощью DropDownList нужные данных, затем в JS выбранный элемент добавляю в таблицу, таким образом.

```
<div>
                <span>
                    @Html.DropDownList("ADList", ViewBag.adname as SelectList, "Пожалуйста,выберите ФИО");
                    <button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Добавить</button>
                </span>

                <table class="table" id="maintable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ФИО</th>                           
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="data-contact-person">                              
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>                      
                    <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md pull-right btn-sm">Сохранить</button>                        
          </div>
```

в JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                       $(document).on("click", ".classAdd", function () { //
                           var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person').length + 1;
                           var a = $("#ADList Option:Selected").text();

                              var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person">' +
                                 '<td class="f-name01">' + a + '</td>' +
                                 '<td> <button type="button" id="btnDelete" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Удалить из списка</button></td>' +
                               '</tr>';
                           $('#maintable').append(contactdiv);
                          });
```

С таблицей всё ок, теперь нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку btnSubmit,в контроллер Create передавалась модель + массив строк (модель) из динамической таблицы. Здесь не понимаю что нет так...делаю так:

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                    var data = JSON.stringify(getAllEmpData)); 
                    $.ajax({    
    url: 'Home/Create',
    type: 'POST',    
    dataType: 'json',    
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',    
   data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),    
   success: function () {    
        alert("ОК");    
   },    
   error: function () {    
        alert("Error");    
    }
```

});

```
});

                function getAllEmpData() {
                       var data = [];
                       $('tr.data-contact-person').each(function () {
                           var firstName = $(this).find('.f-name01').val();
                           var alldata = {
                           'fio': firstName
                       }
                       data.push(alldata);
                       });
                 return data;
                }
```

Но при нажатии на кнопку, попадаю в ветку "Error". Что не так я делаю?

Код контролллера:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,numb,dat,comment,stat,cause")] Order order, string empdata)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Orders.Add(order);
            db.SaveChanges();
            db.Entry(order).GetDatabaseValues();
            var serializeData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<OI>>(empdata);
    int nextID= order.ID;
    далее манипулирую с данными из empdata

            return RedirectToAction("List");
        }
        return View(order);
    }
```

Честно скажу не знаю, как передать в контроллер и модель и данные из динамической таблицы

Comment: уберите оба `stringify` (вы думаете что сервер догадаться должен, что входящую модель надо 2 раза декодировать?) и воспользуйтесь отладчиком, посмотрите, что приходит в ваш метод на стороне сервера. обычно токен еще надо отправлять. + добавьте параметр в функцию ошибки, и посмотрите, что за контент там приходит, обычно там описание ошибки  и приведено

Comment: ок,убрал. выпадает на блоке ajax c ошибкой 0x800a138a - Ошибка выполнения JavaScript: Предполагается наличие функции

Comment: ну дак вызвать эту функцию то может надо? или не понятно чем вы. `data: { empdata: getAllEmpData() },` да и `data.push()` в тело цикла внести бы вам ндо

Comment: ага...я думал,что выражением var data = getAllEmpData(); я вызвал функцию, а затем передаю значение в аяксе data: { 'empdata': data }. ОК. + data.push() я вносил, только писал data.push(alldata). Сделал как вы написали, появилась ошибка invalid json primitive, если все таки в аякс запрос добавить stringify -  data:JSON.stringify({empdata: getAllEmpData()}), ошибок нет, попадаю в нужный контроллер. (контроллер у меня описан так public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,numb,dat,comment,stat,cause")] Order order, string empdata), при этом и модель Order и переданная empdata = null

Comment: это у вас в комментарии написано `data = getAllEmpData()` а в коде выше явно скобок не хватает.

Comment: да, все верно, сори, с телефона набирал

Comment: вы код из контроллера вынесите в вопрос с помощью [edit].  Теперь становится ясно, что в контроллере у вас два параметра - заказ и данные. Вот данные вы пытаетесь собрать. а поля order вообще не видать нигде при отправке.

Comment: Код контроллера добавил в вопрос.